# How to compile ACM sig-alternative template successfully?

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, ps, acm

I am new to texlive. After I downloaded the files from ACM website:

```
Alternate ACM LaTeX2e Style File V2.5 (MAY 2012 CLS)
Alternate ACM LaTeX2e Sample File V2.0 (MAY 2012 LaTeX)
ACM LaTeX2e Sample BIB File
Graphic #1 (EPS)
Graphic #2 (EPS)
Graphic #3 (PS)
```

I used command `pdflatex sig-alternate.tex`. I got an error as below:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
```

While if I use `latex sig-alternate.tex`. The compilation can be done, but with some warnings like:

```
[3]
No file sig-alternate.bbl.
```

I have the file `sigproc.bib`.

And I couldn't open the generated `sig-alternate.dvi` with preview. After `dvipdf sig-alternate.dvi`, I found the **references** section is missing.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the `sigproc.bib` file needs to be compiled between two runs of the `latex`, using the following command:

```
latex sig-alternate
bibtex sig-alternate
latex sig-alternate
```

Note that neither command `bibtex sigproc.bib` or `bibtex sig-alternate.tex` would work.